# What does a RMSE value of 42.3671939 mean?

Tags: statistical-significance

I carried out an experiment where I measured the effect of temperature on the buffer capacity of a solution. I put my data in excel and calculated the RMSE and got 42.3671939. I want to explain the relationship between temperature and buffer capacity and I was wondering what 42.3671939 means.

My data:
temperature:  buffer capacity:
20             0.0723
30             0.0714
40             0.0676
50             0.0635
60             0.015

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! RMSE of what?

Comment: It means nothing unless you can compare this value to something like results of another model.